# Tips for amending apartment/condo bylaws around bike storage

Tags: storage

We are proposing a bylaw ammendment that would allow residents to bring top end bikes to their units. (This after several top end bikes were stolen from our 'secure' bike room.) The challenge we face is educating residents on the difference between top-end bikes and commuters. Most residents group bikes into one category and feel that our public bike room is sufficient. Has anyone tackled this issue with their strata and could share tips on ways to inform/persuade the masses, many of whom do not bike. We need a 3/4 vote to pass this ammendment. Thanks!

Comment: Why should high end bikes be treated any differently? And whats the line between a high end and low end bike? If you're speeding in a ferrari, you're still going to get caught with a ticket just like a fiesta driver.

Comment: What is a strata? (Stratum?) I'm assuming you don't live in a layer of sedimentary rock.

Comment: Do you have secure mounting points to lock your bikes up in the bike room? If not, why not?

Comment: Where is this? In Land of the Free this would be a personal freedom issue, somewhere else something else.

Comment: Also, why limit to high end bikes? Why just not allow all bikes and if it's really a problem, put a sanction on leaving dirt in hallways?

Comment: What is the argument being presented against allowing bikes brought into units? That's important to know that before preparing a counterargument.

Comment: @JamieA  playing Devil's advocate here:   "Bikes clutter up the fire escape/hallway/passages/access"  "bikes are awkward to move and will injure other people"  "Bikes are wet and dirty and oily, and will drop water/mud/oil on the floor/carpet"  "I can't get in the lift/elevator with a bicycle in the way"  "The bike will scratch the paint on the walls"     "Cyclists smell bad"    "I'm offended that you're getting healthy and I'm not so hide the reminder away"

Comment: I've lived in a number of mid to high end apartments in a major city in the US midwest and have never heard of such a prohibition. Can anyone enlighten us to where this is common practice?

Answer (score 6):

Even if it does pass do you realize how hard and emotional this would be to enforce.  You are going to need to tell someone their bike is not high end.  Just give them all the option.  Better yet fix the security issue in the bike room.

Comment: Yeah - the suggestion comes across as "exclusive"   and fixing the cause will work better than treating the symptom.   Good work for having a bike room though.  Hard points will help, as would cages (but they take a lot of room)  as would a CCTV camera aimed at the entry point.

Comment: The access control to the bike room would be off-topic here but is well worth a look.  Do all residents have access, or just those with bikes (and how do you makes sure they they don't just claim to have a bike to gain access)?  How is ex-residents' access revoked?

Answer (score 2):

Make a rule that a bike dis-assembled into wheels and frame can be brought into a unit.

Rationale: Most people don't like bikes indoors because moving them around leaves dirt on the floor and streaks on the wall from the wheels touching them. A disassembled bike is much smaller and needs to be carried - minimising the risk. It involves also some effort - which owners of expensive bikes are more likely to spend if theft has been a problem. And finally, high-end bikes are usually easier to take apart. This rule avoids any discussion about value or high-end. This is my thinking behind the proposed rule.

Addressing comments: I'm not a fan of the proposed rule but I'm trying to answer the question by proposing something that I feel provides owners of expensive bikes a way to store them securely. Of course, a better bike room would be preferable but that wasn't the question.

Comment: I disagree. That makes a distinction based on (frequency of) use, not value. My two commuter bikes cost me £600(new) and £60(old). Some people wouldn't touch either as too cheap and nasty even for riding to work, and would resent the time to dismantle while others race on bikes restored from junkyard finds and would be happy to strip down after every use.

Comment: @ChrisH so you would rather make the distinction on value?

Comment: @njzk2 no, I'd allow all clean bikes. But at least value is an objective measure non-cyclists will understand. It's hard to measure though given how long a bike can last with one owner. Removing and refitting my wheels daily would probably pay for a new bike every few months charged at my hourly rate (which is not huge) but I do have security skewers which slow things down.

Comment: A more technical disagreement is that after removing the back wheel you have a dirty chain flapping around.

Comment: I disagree with the claim that a carried, disassembled bike is less likely to hit the wall than a wheeled assembled one.

Comment: @DavidRicherby especially if you're carrying the bike one one shoulder and the wheels in the other hand -- pressing lift buttons and opening doors is likely to be trciky without bumping into things